# use junit_xml_reporter.html for protractor results

Tags: report, jasmine, protractor

I am using jasmine-reports to report my protractor test results, currently it goes to an XML file, which I know using XSLT i can make it more readable etc.

As part of the Jasmine-reporters kit I notice in the test folder there is the junit_xl_reporter.html file there that makes the reports very readable, and I wonder if anyone knows how I can make that work with my own tests, I've had a play about but I'm not entirely sure what i need to do to get it working